# Javascript `this` changes constantly, don't know why

Tags: javascript, redis, this

Currently, I'm writing an app on Node.js 5.2.0 on a Linux box with Redis and Caminte. When trying to add different prototype methods to a database object, the context of what `this` refers to constantly shifts within our reference. After calling `push` in modelRules.js, `this` shifts types. I was looking for some assistance with:

1. How to consistently reference the instantiation of a specific module (function that accepts a schema object) outside of the module itself. I want to tack on prototype functions such as addModelBelongsTo to a `User` object, and sadly my function simply seems to break when referencing the internal modifiable data members within the class.
2. The proper organization of the prototype accessors. Is there a specific style that should be used when referencing the insides of the instantiations of these classes?
3. Why the instantiation of the class `User` persists data across multiple instantiations of the class? For `self[restructuredModelName]` (type of array), whenever I call this method on one instantiation, another instantiation of the other object already contains the data of the first instantiation. This should not be happening.

User.js

```js
module.exports = function (schema) {
  const IBANVerificationStatusSymbol = Symbol('IBANVerificationStatus');
  const relationalMapper = require('./../relationalMapper');

  const userObj = {
    id: { type: schema.Number },
    firstName: { type: schema.String },
    lastName: { type: schema.String },
    IBAN: { type: schema.String, unique: true },
    IBANVerified: { type: schema.Boolean, default: false },
    IBANVerificationCode: { type: schema.String },
    BIC: { type: schema.String },
    email: { type: schema.String, index: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: schema.String },
    status: { type: schema.Number, default: 0 },
    profilePicture: { type: schema.String },
    phone: { type: schema.String, index: true, unique: true },
    accessToken: { type: schema.String },
    prefix: { type: schema.String, default: '+31' },
    updated: { type: schema.Date, default: Date.now() },
    created: { type: schema.Date, default: Date.now() },
    lastAccessedFeed: { type: schema.Date },
    street: { type: schema.String },
    streetNumber: { type: schema.String },
    postalCode: { type: schema.String },
    city: { type: schema.String },
    country: { type: schema.String },
    FCR: { type: schema.Number, default: 0 },
  };

  // There's GOTTA be a way to typecheck at compilation
  const associationMap = {
    Activity: { belongsTo: 'Activity', hasMany: 'activities' },
    Client: { belongsTo: null, hasMany: 'clients' },
    Group: { belongsTo: 'Group', hasMany: 'groups' },
    Mandate: { belongsTo: null, hasMany: 'mandates' },
    Transaction: { belongsTo: null, hasMany: 'transactions' },
    Update: { belongsTo: null, hasMany: 'updates' },
    Reaction: { belongsTo: null, hasMany: 'reactions' },
  };

  relationalMapper.createRelations(associationMap, userObj, schema);

  const User = schema.define('user', userObj, {

  });

    const setId = function (self, models) {
      //  self.addClients(1);
    };

    User.hooks = {
      afterInitialize: [setId],
    };

    User.prototype.obj = userObj;

    User.associationMap = associationMap;

    User.prototype.associationMap = associationMap;

    return User;
};
```

modelRules.js:

```js
function addModelBelongsTo(modelName, models, modelObjKey, modelRelated) {
    const restructuredModelName = `memberOf${modelName}`;
    const restructuredModelNameCamel = `addMemberOf${modelName}`;
    const currentModels = models;

    currentModels[modelObjKey].prototype[restructuredModelNameCamel] = function(modelId) {
        const self = this;
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if (self[restructuredModelName].indexOf(modelId) <= -1) {
                modelRelated.exists(modelId, function(err, exists) {
                    if (err || !exists) { reject(new Error(err || 'Doesnt exist')); }
                    console.log(`This:${self}\nrestructuredModelName:${JSON.stringify(self[restructuredModelName])}`);
                    self[restructuredModelName].push(modelId);
                    console.log(`This:${self}\nrestructuredModelName:${restructuredModelName}`);
                    self.save((saveErr) => {
                        saveErr ? reject(new Error(saveErr)) : resolve(self);
                    });
                });
            } else {
                reject(new Error(''));
            }
        });
    };
}
```

Comment: Required reading: [How does the “this” keyword work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: Rather than use `self`, use the arrow syntax when you want to preserve `this` reference, and use `function() {` when you want `this` to be based on the owner of the caller. (For instance, in your example, `self = this` should be `currentModels[modelObjKey]`.) Note your inclusion of `function(err, exists)` too.